# Oriantable Smooth Manifold

Tags: proof-verification, smooth-manifolds

The question is that if $M^n=U\cup V$ is a connected smooth manifold with coordinate charts $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ on the open sets $U$ and $V$ respectively with $U\cap V$ is connected, show that $M^n$ is oriantable.

Now if $f:U\cap V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ assigns each point to the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of $\phi_1\circ \phi_2^{-1}$, then since $U\cap V$ is connected the image is either always positive or always negative (since $0$ cannot be in the image). Now in the former case we are done by definition. For the latter case, I considered the coordinate charts $\varphi_1 := \phi_1 $ and $\varphi_2 := -\phi_2$. If I take the same map, now it seems like the image will be always positive.

Is my solution valid?

Edit : For $M=S^1$, the coordinate charts $\phi_1(x,y)=\frac{x}{1-y}$ and $\phi_2(x,y)=\frac{x}{1+y}$ on the open sets $U=S^1-\{(0,1)\}$ and $V=S^1-\{(0,-1)\}$, this $f:U\cap V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is just $f(t)=\frac{-1}{t^2}$ which is always negative. But if I take $\varphi_1(x,y)=\frac{x}{1-y}$ and $\varphi_2(x,y)=\frac{-x}{1+y}$ I get $\frac{1}{t^2}$ which is always positive. Now of course this is not an example since $U\cap V$ is not connected but I guess it shows how the trick works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is basically fine, except for one thing: Replacing $\phi_2$ by $-\phi_2$ will not necessarily change the orientation determined by $\phi_2$. For example, consider the identity chart $\phi_2\colon\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ (that is, $\phi_2(x,y) = (x,y)$).  This is positively oriented, and so is $-\phi_2(x,y) = (-x,-y)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi : U \to \mathbb R^n$ is a chart, then $U$ is orientable. Thus we know $U,V$ are orientable. Because $U\cap V$ is an open subset of $U$ it is orientable. If you choose an orientation for $U$, you have one for $U\cap V$; you can choose an orientation for $V$ that is the same on $U\cap V$ because $U\cap V$ is connected (throughout a connected component the orientation is the same).

Comment: What I asked was a proof verification question. Actually I completely understand your logic however I need to use the definition of orientability using the determinant of the Jacobian of the transition maps.